# UI Controller like in Apple's Book Application?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

First of all I'm new to IOS Development!

I have a plan to build an app which should look similar to the **Book app** provided by Apple. 
My question is, that what kind of UI Controller does that app use for displaying the books on a shelf? 
Is that a custom one? Or just a couple of UIImageView's placed on a UIView?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom view created by Apple but it wouldn't be too difficult to replicate with a background image and a UIScrollView where the books are placed based on calculation on spacing

Edit: Maybe using a Library such as [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) would help you with the spacing of the books on the Shelf

Comment: AQGridView looks exactly what I need! Thanks!I will also check UIScrollView.